# Gitlab CI timeout manual job

Tags: gitlab

I have a pipeline with 4 stages:

- compile
- test
- package
- deploy

The package stage is manual. I would like the pipeline to timeout if no manual action has been taken after x minutes. I know that there is a `timeout` option but it's only taken into account after the job started.

```
package_staging:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: package
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -DskipTests clean install -Pstaging
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
    - /^release/.*$
  when: manual
```

Comment: try to set a variable and check after the timeout if the variable is set (true/false)

Comment: I have the same question and no help from documentation... :/

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no such feature. Consider upvoting and commenting with your use case on the relevant feature request issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29574

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem right, you want to achieve the following:

if manual action is triggered --> run package and deploy stage jobs
if manual action is triggered --> do not run deploy stage jobs

This can be achieved by using the `needs` keyword for your `deploy` stage jobs, where your need is a dependency to the manual job (which would need `allow_failure:true` in order to keep the pipeline working) - as this can lead to other problems, this seems to be no good solution.

#### Correct behavior

In terms of correctness, you could do the following:

1. change your `package_staging` job to make use of the `trigger` keyword

   1. your manual job will trigger a separate pipeline that contains two jobs
2. the child pipeline (triggered in 1.) will

   1. first build your project
   2. deploy it to the desired location

In case this is the correct understanding of your problem, I could come up with a more extensive example